# if sound is playing jquery

Tags: jquery, audio

I have a menu with a mouseouver event that triggers a sound file to start playing. Trouble is if the user mouseover another one of the links in the menu, the sound plays again.

What I am trying to figure out is how to only play one sound at a time? ie. wait until current sound has finished playing before starting it again?

Any ideas?

Here the code that I have in place at the moment. It uses the jQuery.sound.js plugin.

```
.mouseover(function(){
$.fn.soundPlay({url: 'images/casino.wav'});
})
```

cheers!
Dec

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to have a callback that will fire when the sound has stopped playing. However, I don't think that there is a plugin that supports something like this:

```
$.fn.soundPlay({url: 'images/casino.wav', 
                finishedPlaying: function() {}});
```

If you had this, you could disable mouseover when a sound starts playing and enable it again when it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can wait for the soundPlay function to end like normal jquery functions.

If you know how long the sound lasts I would look to have a variable which is turned on and off using the known duration:

```
var soundPlaying = false;
.mouseover(function(){
    if (!soundPlaying) {
       $.fn.soundPlay({url: 'images/casino.wav'});
       soundPlaying = true;
       setTimeout('soundPlaying = false;',1000);
     }
});
```

I have assumed 1000 ms as the duration of the sound being played.